# SHP from tmap object

Tags: gis, tmap

Could someone tell me how to create a shape file (to use in GIS software) from a tmap object created in R?

I have something like this:

```
Map <- tm_shape (raster) + tm_raster() + tm_shape(shape) + tm_borders()
```

I know that tmap_save allows me to save the Map object in various formats but raster and SHP.

I would like to save Map as a SHP file so that it can be made available for use in GIS software.